# Determine some functions are convex or not

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are convex functions from $\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}.$ By giving either a proof or counterexample, decide whether the following functions are convex or not.
>
> Hint: think about the functions, $x$ and $-x$
>
> $a)f(x)g(x)$
>
> $b)f(g(x))$
>
> $c)f(x)^3$

---

By definition

A function $h$ defined on a convex set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a convex function if $$h(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\le\lambda h(x_1)+(1-\lambda)h(x_2)$$
for $0\le\lambda\le1, \forall x_1,x_2\in S$

My attempts

$a)$ Not always convex, here is a counter example.

Let $x_1:=2,\space x_2:=1,\space\lambda:=\frac{1}{2},\space f(x):=-x,\space g(x):=x,h(x):=f(x)g(x),\space \text{then }h(x)=-x^2$

That $x$ and $-x$ are both convex

$\text{WTS }h(x) \text{is not convex}$

If not we have:

$$h(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\le\lambda h(x_1)+(1-\lambda)h(x_2)$$

$$\Rightarrow-(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)^2\le\lambda (-x_1^2)+(1-\lambda)(-x_2^2)$$

$$\Rightarrow-(\frac{1}{2}2+(1-\frac{1}{2})1)^{2}\le\frac{1}{2} (-2^2)+(1-\frac{1}{2})(-1^2)$$

$$\Rightarrow-2.25\le-2.5\tag*{$(\Rightarrow\Leftarrow)$}$$

$b)$ Not always convex, here is a counter example.

Let $x_1:=2,\space x_2:=1,\space\lambda:=\frac{1}{2},\space f(x):=-x,\space g(x):=x^2,h(x):=f(g(x)),\space \text{then }h(x)=-x^2$

That $x^2$ and $-x$ are both convex

$\text{WTS }h(x) \text{is not convex}$

If not we have:$($same as $a))$

$$h(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\le\lambda h(x_1)+(1-\lambda)h(x_2)$$

$$\Rightarrow-(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)^2\le\lambda (-x_1^2)+(1-\lambda)(-x_2^2)$$

$$\Rightarrow-(\frac{1}{2}2+(1-\frac{1}{2})1)^{2}\le\frac{1}{2} (-2^2)+(1-\frac{1}{2})(-1^2)$$

$$\Rightarrow-2.25\le-2.5\tag*{$(\Rightarrow\Leftarrow)$}$$
$c)$ Not always convex, here is a counter example.

Let $x_1:=2,\space x_2:=1,\space\lambda:=\frac{1}{2},\space f(x):=-x, \space h(x):=f(x)^3,\space \text{then }h(x)=-x^3$

That $-x$ is convex

$\text{WTS }h(x) \text{is not convex}$

If not we have:

$$h(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\le\lambda h(x_1)+(1-\lambda)h(x_2)$$

$$\Rightarrow -(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)^3\le\lambda (-x_1^3)+(1-\lambda)(-x_2^3)$$

$$\Rightarrow -(\frac{1}{2} 2+(1-\frac{1}{2})1)^3\le\frac{1}{2} (-2^3)+(1-\frac{1}{2})(-1^3)$$

$$\Rightarrow -3.375\le-4.5\tag*{$(\Rightarrow\Leftarrow)$}$$

---

So all of them are not always convex (is this correct?)$\dots$I'm a little confused about the hint. For example, for $b)$ there is no way to construct a counter example only use $x$ and $-x$.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: The definition of a convex function is $h \left( \lambda x_1 + \left( 1 - \lambda \right) x_2 \right) \leq \lambda h \left( x_1 \right) + \left( 1 - \lambda \right) h \left( x_2 \right)$, where $\lambda \in \left[ 0, 1 \right]$.

Comment: You are right. b) cannot be answered using only the functions $x$ and $-x$.